# noda time: how to represent "standard time"

Tags: c#, nodatime

I receive data from a text file where the dates are often in "standard time" (like Central Standard Time, or Eastern Standard Time.  I specifically mean that *no daylight savings adjustments are observed*).  Using Noda Time, I'm trying to figure out the best way to represent this.

My first thought was that I should make a DateTimeZone for this.  I noticed that some "standard time" zones are included in the tz database (for example, "America/Cancun" can be used for Eastern Standard Time), but other time zones don't seem to have anything to represent their "standard time" variant in the database.

Then I thought I should make an Offset, or make a DateTimeZone straight from the Offset, but I can't seem to find a way to grab the base offset of a DateTimeZone.  For time zones in the continental US, I'm pretty sure I could just do `DateTimeZone.ForOffset(localTimeZone.MinOffset)` (where `localTimeZone` is a DateTimeZone), but I highly doubt that would work in some of the more bizarre time zones.  I also tried
`DateTimeZone.ForOffset(localTimeZone.GetZoneInterval(SystemClock.Instance.GetCurrentInstant()).StandardOffset)`
but that's so roundabout that I suspect there's a reason why it's incorrect.

I *could* just store the raw offset associated with each file provider, but configuring the application is a lot easier if the configuration says it's in Central Standard Time rather than if it says it has an offset of -6.

Am I missing a way to do this?  Or is there something wrong with how I'm conceptualizing the problem, such that this isn't the right approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't necessarily a single "base offset" for a `DateTimeZone`. It can change over time. For example, the standard time in most of Alaska changed in 1983 from UTC-10 to UTC-9.

Now that *may* not be a problem for the time zones you're interested in... in which case, you could use the approach of "find the standard offset for the local time zone at the current instant, then create a constant-offset `DateTimeZone` from that". I would probably use three statements rather than your current mega-expression, but it would do what you want.

If you want a time zone which is equivalent to an existing time zone, including any changes to its standard offset, but without any daylight saving time, that's rather harder to achieve. It *can* be done, but it wouldn't be terribly simple. You'd probably want your own `DateTimeZone` subclass that accepts an existing `DateTimeZone` and iterates over all `ZoneInterval` values from the start of time until some suitable end point (e.g. 2200, as a far-future date that won't have any rule changes specified after it for quite a while) and work out your *new* `ZoneInterval` values. I could provide a sample implementation of that if you want, but you'd really want to think about whether it was what you wanted first...

Here's some code to show you all the time zones which have changed their standard offset at some point between 1930 and 2100 - obviously you can change the interval easily to change the criteria to match your context more closely.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using NodaTime;
using NodaTime.Extensions;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Instant min = Instant.FromUtc(1930, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
        Instant max = Instant.FromUtc(2100, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);

        foreach (var zone in DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb.GetAllZones())
        {
            var initialStandard = zone.GetZoneInterval(min).StandardOffset;
            var zoneIntervals = zone.GetZoneIntervals(min, max);
            var firstChange = zoneIntervals.FirstOrDefault(zi => zi.StandardOffset != initialStandard);
            if (firstChange != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(zone.Id);
                Console.WriteLine($"Initial standard offset: {initialStandard}");
                Console.WriteLine($"First different standard offset: {firstChange}");
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll go with the constant-offset `DateTimeZone` with the standard offset from the current instant.  All of our inputs are in present time, so I don't need to worry much about representing times before and after a change to the base offset.  (Once we load an input, I can represent it with just an `Instant`).